# What is this fluctuation I get when I use the DC electronic load?

Tags: voltage, dc-dc-converter, oscilloscope, buck, emc

I have a buck converter. I am loading the buck converter using an electronic load - [EA-EL 9200-18T](https://elektroautomatik.com/shop/en/products/programmable-dc-electronic-loads-br-conventional-and-regenerative/series-el-9000-t-br-conventional-electronic-loads-br-400w-up-to-600w/113/electronic-dc-load-0...200v/0...18a)

When I load 100mA at the output of the buck converter, I get this waveform:

[image]
To try to find out what the fluctuation is, I changed output current scope channel to AC coupling mode and got this:

[image]

The frequency of the output current fluctuation happens to be around 120kHz. Where does this 120kHz come from, and how can I eliminate it?

Even with the DC electronic load turned OFF, and all the input voltages turned OFF, but (the equipment is connected), I get this 120kHz:

[image]

I also see a low frequency riding on top of the signal :

[image]

However, If I use a rheostat as the DC load for the buck converter, I am not getting any fluctuations as shown below:

[image]

Can someone tell me from where the 120kHz is coming from and how to eliminate it?

In some cases, I get 50Hz fluctuation riding on the signals. I suppose that is because of the electricity (AC frequency of 50Hz - which powers the oscilloscope and other electronic equipment's in the test bench) coming from the power outlets which couple to the oscilloscope probes via air. Am I correct?

Comment: Let's see the rheostat load with the same vertical scale so it's possible to make a direct comparison between the two.

Comment: Looks like your electronic load might be oscillating.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Could you please tell me what you mean by oscillating? Like what is happening internally inside the DC Electronic load?

Comment: @Andyaka , could you please explain me what do you mean by "load might be oscillating" ?

Comment: Well, I made that comment before you disclosed what the load was. Now that I see it is a properly designed electronic load I doubt that will happen.

Comment: Could you please tell me what you think the reason maybe

Answer (score 0):

It could be common-mode noise.

You stipulate you have a buck converter, guessing it is a DC/DC converter which implies you have a power supply powering your buck.

120khz is typical from a switched power supply and they generate usually quite a bit of noise and ripple.

Try to add capacitors and also common mode choke at the output of your supply, eventually a capacitor multiplier, and see if that reduces the noise.

Comment: Ensure twisted pairs are used to help reject Vcm noise pickup and increase common mode capacitance or lower Zcm with a shield. Or lower inductance between grounds

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So, when you say, "120khz is typical from a switched power supply" - It means the power supply which is powering my Buck Converter is the one which is providing the 120kHz ripple ?

Comment: It is quite likely @Newbie and what I infer in my answer

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In the real scenario, there is going to be a battery which is going to power the buck converter. And there is no switched power supply over there. So, I think I don't have to add caps and CMC. So, is there a way to eliminate this noise by other means, apart from your suggestion?

Comment: @Newbie such noise is a property of buck/boost converters, they all introduce switching noise at khz/mhz range (mostly khz usually). You could go for higher frequency and put a small cap on the output (which would also be recommended to have with the battery). But buck converter means noise. You want clean - you go with linear regulators (at the expense of efficiency).

Comment: So, when you mean "120khz is typical from a switched power supply", you meant the actual buck converter, right?

Comment: @Newbie can you post a picture of your setup ? How do you power your buck ?

Comment: I am powering my Buck Converter using this Power Supply - https://elektroautomatik.com/shop/en/products/programmable-dc-laboratory-power-supplies/dc-laboratory-power-supplies/series-psi-9000-t-br-320w-up-to-1.5kw/515/lab-power-supply-0...200v/0...25a.

Comment: have you tried to measure the supply output in AC mode with the spectrometer using a resistor as a load? @Newbie